# How can I stop mutliple requests being submitted at the same time for angular?

Tags: angular, caching, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular 5 and I'm noticing a lot of repeat HTTP calls.  In one example i'm getting some reference data, which will hardly ever change.  I'm trying to reuse as much of these calls as possible but can't seem to stop the calls being made.  I'm using a Jasmine test to show the problem.

I've tried `shareReplay`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

@Injectable()
class ApiService {
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getValue = () => this.http.get("").map(x => x).shareReplay(1);
}
describe("ApiService",
    () => {
        let apiService: ApiService;
        let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [],
                imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
                providers: [ApiService]
            }).compileComponents();

            apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
            httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        });

        it("getValue for api called twice makes one call",
            () => {
                apiService.getValue().subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));
                apiService.getValue().subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));

                httpMock.expectOne("").flush(1); // Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: ", found 2 requests.
            });
    });
```

and I've tried caching

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs/ReplaySubject";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

declare type GetDataHandler<T> = () => Observable<T>;

export class Cacheable<T> {

    protected data: T;
    protected subjectData: Subject<T>;
    protected observableData: Observable<T>;
    public getHandler: GetDataHandler<T>;

    constructor() {
        this.subjectData = new ReplaySubject(1);
        this.observableData = this.subjectData.asObservable();
    }

    public getData(): Observable<T> {
        if (!this.getHandler) {
            throw new Error("getHandler is not defined");
        }
        if (!this.data) {
            this.getHandler().map((r: T) => {
                this.data = r;
                return r;
            }).subscribe(
                result => this.subjectData.next(result),
                err => this.subjectData.error(err)
            );
        }
        return this.observableData;
    }

    public resetCache(): void {
        this.data = null;
    }

    public refresh(): Observable<T> {
        this.resetCache();
        return this.getData();
    }

}

@Injectable()
class CacheableApiService {
    private serverList = new Cacheable<any>();

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this.serverList.getHandler = () => this.http.get("").map(x => x).shareReplay(1);
    }

    getValue = () => this.serverList.getData();
}

describe("CacheableApiService",
    () => {
        let cacheableApiService: CacheableApiService;
        let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [],
                imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
                providers: [CacheableApiService]
            }).compileComponents();

            cacheableApiService = TestBed.get(CacheableApiService);
            httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        });

        it("getValue called twice makes one call",
            () => {
                cacheableApiService.getValue().subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));
                cacheableApiService.getValue().subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));

                httpMock.expectOne("").flush(1); // Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: ", found 2 requests.
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in these cases is that you are creating a cached stream *twice*.

If you rewrote your test to be like this, I expect it would pass.

```
it("getValue for api called twice makes one call",
        () => {
            const stream = apiService.getValue();
            stream.subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));
            stream.subscribe(x => expect(x).toBe(1));

            httpMock.expectOne("").flush(1); // should work now
        });
```

If you want your method to return the same stream each time it is called, that is a problem that isn't really related to streams. You just want to memoize that function - there's lots of ways to do that! Here is a completely naive approach:

```
@Injectable()
class ApiService {
  private source: Observable<any>; // horrible typing, please don't do this for real
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  getValue = () => {
    if ( !this.source ) {
      this.source = this.http.get("").map(x => x).shareReplay(1);
    }
    return this.source;
  }
}
```

You might also be interested in making the stream a property and consuming it directly, rather than trying to return it from a method. Since streams are "lazy", you don't need functions to provide them to your consumers.